# Non-greedy match between two strings using parsec or attoparsec in Haskell

Tags: regex, parsing, haskell

Here is the problem I'm struggling with.

Using parser combinators like `parsec` or `attoparsec`, I want to match **"match me"** in the following string:

*"front noise match after this string **match me** match before me match before me back noise"*

where `front noise`, `match me`, `back noise` can be any string

Here is the regex version of a solution to the problem:

```
(?<=match after this string)(.*?)(?=match before me)
```

As you can see it's non-greedy `(.*?)`. In other words, it won't match **"match me match before me"** as `(.*)` would.

### For the record, here are some of the many miserable attempts of mine

In parsec there is `between`, but I'm confused about how to use it. [The documentation for it](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec3-1.0.0.9/docs/Text-Parsec.html) has the example `braces  = between (symbol "{") (symbol "}")`, but I can't even get the example itself working.

I've also tried things like `between (string "start") (many anyChar) (string "end")` on "start match end", but it did not work either:

```
unexpected " "
expecting "end"
```

Another thing I've tried was this, which of course would not work with any noise:

```
(string "start") *> (many anyChar) <* (string "end")
```

but it did not work either:

```
Prelude Control.Applicative Text.Parsec P> let betw = (string "start") *> (many anyChar) <* (string "end")
Prelude Control.Applicative Text.Parsec P> test betw "start match end"
Left (line 1, column 16):
unexpected end of input
expecting "end"
```

After a couple more decades of experimentation, I've started trying things like

`manyTill anyChar (string "start")` on "noise start match end"

```
unexpected " "
expecting "start"
```

Comment: I believe you'll have to use lookAhead for this.

Comment: This feels a little [XY problemish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Parsing is about completely analysing your data from the ground up, rather than chopping it into smaller and smaller bits. What were you trying to achieve, and can it really be true that you want absolutely any data whatsoever, just as long as it's between "start" and "end"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with the comment that you might want to take a more high-level approach.

Nevertheless, it's possible to solve it this way using parsec, and you're almost there. Using `manyTill` works, but it doesn't yet match noise in the beginning. So use it twice:

```
GHCi> let test = manyTill anyChar (string "start") *> manyTill anyChar (string "end")
GHCi> parseTest test "foo start match end"
" match "
```

There's still a problem, though:

```
GHCi> parseTest test "noise start match end"
parse error at (line 1, column 5):
unexpected "e"
expecting "tart"
```

Parsec doesn't backtrack by default, so seeing the `s` in `noise` makes Parsec expect the rest of `start`. In order to prevent this, you have to use `try` for both the "separators":

```
GHCi> let test = manyTill anyChar (try $ string "start") *> manyTill anyChar (try $ string "end")
GHCi> parseTest test "noise start match end"
" match "
```